# JSON get the value of its name attribute

Tags: c#

I have an JSON result like this

```
 {
        "responseHeader": {
            "status": 0,
            "QTime": 1,
            "params": {
                "q": "zip:15241",
                "wt": "json",
                "fq": "propertyType:AUCTION"
            }
        },
        "response": {
            "numFound": 2,
            "start": 0,
            "docs": [{
                "streetAddress": "1014 TALL TREES DR",
                "estimate": 506672.0,
                "city": "PITTSBURGH",
                "beds": 4.0,
                "baths": 3.5,
                "propertyType": "AUCTION",
                "status": "OPEN",
                "propertyId": 778526,
                "amountField": "OB",
                "amount": "88888.0",
                "enteredDate": 20101221,
                "bed_bath": "4B 3.50BT",
                "hasPhoto": false,
                "auctionDate": "2012-08-07T18:30:00Z",
                "displayAddress": "TALL TREES DR",
                "zip": "15241",
                "residenceType": "SFR",
                "sqFeet": 3275.0,
                "fcStatusName": "NTS",
                "county": "Allegheny",
                "state": "PA",
                "_version_": 1429451140939907072
            }, {
                "streetAddress": "2567 ROSSMOOR DR",
                "estimate": 503195.0,
                "city": "PITTSBURGH",
                "beds": 6.0,
                "baths": 2.0,
                "propertyType": "AUCTION",
                "status": "OPEN",
                "propertyId": 1662435,
                "amountField": "MV",
                "amount": "503195.0",
                "enteredDate": 20101221,
                "bed_bath": "6B 2BT",
                "hasPhoto": false,
                "auctionDate": "2010-12-24T18:30:00Z",
                "displayAddress": "ROSSMOOR DR",
                "zip": "15241",
                "residenceType": "SFR",
                "sqFeet": 6143.0,
                "fcStatusName": "NTS",
                "county": "Allegheny",
                "state": "PA",
                "_version_": 1429451149353680896
            }]
        }
    }
```

I want to get a list of objects, and every object will contain the value of streetAddress, estimate, city etc...

So how can access these elements by name?

Comment: Your comment is tagged `C#`, but you didn't say which .NET library you're using to parse JSON.

Comment: Piggy-backing what Joe White said, have you built your object to serialize into?

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771707/jstree-json-issue/16773055#16773055 this might help.

Comment: in short, you'll need to create an Object Model like @DimitarDimitrov said, and use the [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library to deserialize your JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well looking at your json input (and assuming that you're using C# indicated by your tag), also provided that I understand your question correct.
You can do the following:

Create some objects that you can map to, In [VS2012 Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx) you can *copy the JSON that you provided in your question -> open a .cs file -> right-click -> paste special -> "Paste JSON as Classes"*, which would generate the following:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Responseheader responseHeader { get; set; }
    public Response       response       { get; set; }
}

public class Responseheader
{
    public int    status  { get; set; }
    public int    QTime   { get; set; }
    public Params _params { get; set; }
}

public class Params
{
    public string q  { get; set; }
    public string wt { get; set; }
    public string fq { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public int   numFound { get; set; }
    public int   start    { get; set; }
    public Doc[] docs     { get; set; }
}

public class Doc
{
    public string   streetAddress  { get; set; }
    public float    estimate       { get; set; }
    public string   city           { get; set; }
    // etc ...
}
```

Then you could use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) (which you can also get from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json)) to de-serialize the input into a proper C# object, like this:

```
Rootobject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonInput);
```

And of course you can now access any of it's properties like -> `rootObject.response.docs` etc.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @ArulDinesh :) You got it, mate